# how to link .so files from local aar module in android to application android.mk file

Tags: android, aar

my project dependancy is like below

App -> lib1 -> lib2

gradle dependency for lib1 is like below

dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib2') // since this library source is available locally
}

some of the native files in lib1 are using functions in lib2.

problem :
    gradle build is failing, undefined reference to functions in lib2 while linking lib2 in lib1.

i referred https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/enable-arcore, but my gradle build is failing, since my library project source are available locally.

Comment: referencing some web-site is insufficient. those 3 `build.gradle` would permit to understand the problem. `Android.mk` also hints for `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`. better use `cmake` instead.

Answer (score 0):

That one local library depends on another local library, within the same project, might be the root cause for these issues. Merging these two libraries might be the most easy way out of the situation produced by these cross-module dependencies... which must only exist once in the final package.

Comment: How to merge two libraries?

Comment: just take the code of the one and drop it into the other... refactoring is easy with an IDE. this eliminates any cross-module dependencies which might exist - and completely circumvents the problem you are facing. you'd still could organize them into two packages, but they have to be in the same module.